# how to make 10PRINT in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make 10PRINT in javascript but I'm getting an out-of-memory error.
it's supposed to output something like this:
///////\///\///\////////\\/\\///\\///
here is the code:

```
let st = []
let i = 0
let i2 = 0
while(i < 10)
{
    while(i2 < 10)
    {
        if(Math.random() > 0.5)
        {
            st.push("/")
        }else
        {
            st.push("  ⃥")
        }
    }
    i2 = 0
    console.log(st)
    st = {}
}
```

can somebody tell me why it's not working?

Comment: When do you expect `i2 < 10` or `i < 10` to be false? What is the purpose of `i2 = 0` inside the loop or of `st = {}`? Read the documentation: [`while`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while), [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [What’s the difference between “{}” and “\[\]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](/q/33514915/4642212). The entire code can be replaced by `console.log(Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => (Math.random() < 0.5 ? "/" : "\\")).join(""));`. Why do you have _nested_ loops?

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian Simon stated, `i` and `i2` are never modified in the loops, so they will never reach `10`, thus making the program run till the end of time (or end of memory, in your case).

I suggest replacing the `while`s with `for` loops, assuming `i` and `i2` need to be incremented sequentially.